# FTP connection problems on one site for me only

Tags: ftp

I am a website programmer and I access many sites through filezila ftp client. All of a sudden, since yesterday, I have been for the most part unable to connect to just one of my sites -- I get a message "connection time out could not connect to server".

This is a site I've been working on for months and until yesterday, there were never any connection problems. And I am having no FTP connection problems with any other of my websites.

It is definitely not a problem of having the wrong credentials, such as password, because even since yesterday when the problems began, every so often it does let me in. When I did a ping, the numbers looked fine.

If I try to connect via ftp via the browser, it does connect.

My computer is Windows 7. I have a second computer which is an Apple, and there too, I cannot connect via Filezila.

My colleagues who work in a different city nearby tell me they are having no such problems. And I'm pretty sure they are also using Filezila.

I just spoke with my ISP. They said that since I am able to connect ftp via my browser, it cannot be an ISP issue. The tech guy switched some of my browser settings in hopes of solving the problem, but it had no effect.

Comment: Since using FileZilla, ask them to review the logs and see if that helps. Also, ensure they didn't make an update to the server's firewall settings or your own. Did any antivirus software change/update ? Whilst your question is clear (+1) it's sadly very broad

Comment: @oyvey : What is the version of your Filezilla client?. It seems to be a TLS cert issue.

Comment: It seems better today. Go figure.